# is there any way to update data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to change the data from mongoDB

```
{
"ainList" : [ 
    {"evaluation" : "ERROR"}
    ]
}
```

This is the shape of mongdb data which is json

So if know the query to change like this

```
{
"ainList" : [ 
    {"evaluation" : "NORMAL"}
    ]
}
```

Please teach me thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find full [MongoDb Reference here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-arrayfilters)

The Syntax for [Update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update) Operation

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,  //query to match document to be updated
   <update>,
   {
     upsert: <boolean>,
     multi: <boolean>,    
     writeConcern: <document>,
     collation: <document>,
     arrayFilters: [ <filterdocument1>, ... ], // Starting from v3.6 
   }
)
```

And the Solution for your problem.

```
db.collection.update(
   {},
   { $set: { "ainList.$[element].evaluation" : "NORMAL" } },
   {
     multi: true,
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.evaluation": { $eq: "ERROR" } } ]
   }
)
```

**Note:-** Change the `collection` after `db.` with your collection name.